# How can I know which version of my code is running on Openshift?

Tags: openshift

In Openshift, all the automatic `buildconfigs` and `deploymentconfigs` watch a `docker` image tag, and trigger a deploy or build when there is a new image pushed to the Docker registry.

However, my problem is that when I do `oc rollout history dc/<myapp> --revision 15`, there is no way to know which image was running in this revision. There is an attribute saying `image: my-repository>/<my-image>:latest`, but the `latest` at this moment might be different than the `latest` currently running, for example when doing a rollback.

Is there a reliable way of finding out which container is currently running on Openshift?

Comment: Are you saying you set up the deployment configuration to reference an image in an external registry directly? You are better off using an image stream as intermediary. That is, us ``oc import-image`` to create an image stream for your external image. You can then use tags on the image stream to refer to specific versions of your external image, and have the deployment config reference the tag of the image stream when deploying, for the version you want. This avoids problems of relying on ``latest`` tags in images, which aren't particularly useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Yes, this was my problem. If you answer, I'll accept.